# Adding significant stars' row with existing output in R

Tags: r, row, significance

I got column means and range(min, max) from my data.

```
df=matrix(c(3, 5, 2, 3, 6, 3,4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3,5, 5, 5),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(df)<-paste0("ch", 1:ncol(df))
rownames(df)<-paste0("G", 1:nrow(df))
mean<- colMeans(df, na.rm = FALSE, dims = 1)
range<-apply(df, 2, range)
rownames(range) <- c("min","max")
res<-rbind(mean,range)
```

I have a standard mean value(4). Now I want to add additional row showing significant marks(**) with the existing output. Mean values less than 4  were considered significant. Somehow I got significant marks but I failed to add this with the existing result.

```
 f<-res[1,] <4
test <- factor(f, labels=c("Ns", "**"))
result<-rbind(mean,range,test)
result
     ch1 ch2 ch3
mean   4 4.8 3.4
min    3 4.0 2.0
max    5 6.0 5.0
test   1 1.0 2.0
```

I wanted this like following one

```
     ch1 ch2 ch3
mean   4 4.8 3.4
min    3 4.0 2.0
max    5 6.0 5.0
test   Ns Ns **
```

I need your help to solve this.

Comment: Try `data.frame(rbind(mean, range, as.character(test)))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
rbind.data.frame(mean = mean, range, test = as.character(test))

#       ch1 ch2 ch3
# mean   4 4.8 3.4
# min    3   4   2
# max    5   6   5
# test  Ns  Ns  **
```

See `?rbind.data.frame` for a detail.

Answer (score 1):

I think, Matrix can only store the data that have same type. Here, the first three rows are numeric. However, the `test` is `factor`, and it's coerced to numeric, that `Ns` and `**` mapping to `1` and `2`.
I suggest you should use `data.frame` to do it.

```
res<-rbind(mean,range)
res<-data.frame(t(res))
f<-res[1,] <4
test <- factor(f, labels=c("Ns", "**"))
res<-cbind(res,test)
```

I hope this ansewer can help you!